# Controlling Windows/Information PYQT4

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

Alright so this is a specific question about data transfer using different windows in pyqt4. Basically I have 3 windows, each with its own class definition, that I have designed for a project but I'm confused about how to properly arrange these windows.

Ideal Functionality:

Let's say I have 3 windows; A, B, and C. Window A gives me two lists. When I click a button in Window A, window B pops up and gets me a number. After it gives me this number I want window C to open and window B to close but I want window C to have the two lists and the number.

Problems I have:

Currently I make a function in the class for window A to open window B and once I get the number from window B, then window C is created with the information, but it closes since I close window B. Previously I tried keeping window A opening window B and C but it opens the windows at the same time but I need window B to open for its data to then create window C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C` have to be child of `A` than you can close `B`. `B` can call function in parent `A` to open `C` and then `B` can close itself.

Comment: I'm a bit confused to how that would work out. Would you mind explaining? I think I have found a different solution, that required a very minor tweak to making the C window a class variable in my window B class. This causes my window B to close while window C remains open.

Comment: In `A` you create two functions - first ('openB') opens window `B`, second ('openC') opens window `C`. You use `openB` to open window `B`. Then in windows `B` you call `parent.openC(some_arguments)` and parent (`A`) opens windows `C` - and `A` is parent of `C`. When you close `B` (it automaticly close its children) it doesn't close `C` because `C` is not child of `B`.